# How to make my Asp.net webforms Application as Progressive web application with dynamic file to cache

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, progressive-web-apps

i have tried to make my Asp.net Application as a progressive web application and i successfully made one. but the thing is there any way to cache my pages without being shown in serviceworker. because there might be security issue if someone knows my actual page name for example.
./Checkout.aspx.. etc

Comment: Show us and explain what you've already attempted.

Answer (score 0):

### you can make an Asp.net Web app as PWA but dynamic files are not yet supported.

Sure you can , but the dynamic pages for cache will be a geniue
on your pre-cache files you must have to provide an array of items (Files/Images) to be cached

- pages
- images
- js files 
  etc
  you need to provide files to cache and your service worker will be public too.